# How do I fork a specific Github tree?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

Apologies if I'm using the wrong terminology (which I should be doing since my Google searches don't give me what I'm looking for)
I'm learning from an online coding project and they have some code online. However, since it's a class, the files get updated every lesson so there are different trees (?) that we can access. For example, I'm trying to get the files from: https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/launch-with-code/tree/c445cb45c692d12d95864893d95f8b65c

Since for some reason, the copy that I've made following the class (which is the exact same doesn't work...) doesn't work.

I've managed to make a clone of it into my Github, and although I've got the Windows Github client open, I can see the files at that time but don't know how to get the files from that specific time. Opening the folder in File Explorer only has the latest version...

I'm doing this so I can just copy and paste the files into my source code and see if it works. I've no idea what to do and want to continue in the lesson since I want to learn as much as I can because I'm attending a hackathon next weekend.

Please ask clarifying questions since I'm pretty sure I didn't explain this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "tree", I assume you  mean "commit" (this is the Git term for what other SCMs call a revision)

- Open the Git Shell (Github for Windows should have installed a start menu shortcut for you).
- Go to the directory where you have your repository.
- Type `git checkout c445cb45c692d12d95864893d95f8b65c`

This will checkout the specific commit you want.

Note: this will put your working copy in a "detached state", meaning you're not on a specific branch. If you plan to do some work and commit it from this state, you should create a branch:

```
git branch yourbranchname
```

Comment: thanks so much!
coding is tough enough already when things are working. :)